# Selecting an element with no particular id, class, xpath, etc

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, xpath, junit

I am currently working on writing the test automation for a web application that loads as an SWF file for our end-users, but a fully functioning Javascript version exists for the sole purpose of automation.

I have means to navigate through the application with keyboard shortcuts, but when it comes to executing click commands, I have no luck at all. Upon inspecting with Firebug/Firepath, the only value that I could find was an xpath (no id exists, no class, no anything really).

The next issue is the xpath itself.
It is:

1. Really brittle.

   ```
   .//*[@id='flow']/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/img
   ```
2. This appears to be the xpath to the image that represents the button, not the button itself.

Executing `.click()` commands on the above type of xpath will do nothing until you manually hover your mouse over the button (regardless of moveToElement commands), where it will "click" the image but no functionality will run.

So I'm wondering after digging around in the actual JavaScript looking for identifiers, is there any way to select an element through any other properties? Or is there any way I can better "identify" a function? Perhaps find the xpath to the button that the image represents?

Using JUnit and Java, if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: you need to add more details, like html sample, for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: What test framework do you use for executing the HTML? Does the `img` have a click-handler, or is it one of its parents? With Selenium, for instance, you can send a click event to any given element, and if that XPath is correct with any rendering of the page, it should work, provided even propagation is not disabled on the element.

Comment: If you need _"the button itself"_, use _Inspect Element_ from the browser to find out what the actual element is you need and simply remove from the right-hand side of your XPath expression enough axis steps that select the ancestor element that is the button.

Comment: Thanks @Abel! It's a bit of a hassle but it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Since it answered your question, I have changed it into an answer, which, if you like, you can [mark as accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Apparently, my comments answered the OP's question, so here goes, for reference sake:*

If you need *"the button itself"*, as you wrote in your question, use *Inspect Element* from the browser to find out what the actual element is you need and then simply remove from the right-hand side of your XPath expression enough axis steps until the part that remains selects the ancestor element that is the actual button element.

Now you should be able to send it a click event.

I'm afraid there won't be much we can do about the XPath statement to be "brittle", simply because you do not have an identifier to go on. That means that if the structure of the page changes, you will have to change the XPath (unless some of the ancestor elements have some notable identifiers).

Comment: Most of my issues I've been having all seem to be the application itself. It's crazy that they didn't build any identifiers for our functions. So lets say the application's layout gets updated, that means it's now my job to fix all those xpaths, right?

Would it be a crazy/inappropriate question to ask the developers to build identifiers in? It seems it would make my work load a lot lighter.

Comment: @brightbomb, no, that's a very normal request. Though, unless the HTML is meant for machine analyzing and querying, it stands to reason that they didn't build those pages with data-mining in mind. I know you are just testing, and for that it would certainly be better to have IDs.

Comment: Regardless, thanks Abel! I've just began my QA internship and I've been looking for that answer for a while now.